# wordpress target dont validate

Tags: wordpress, target

I get into a problem... I use for all the sponsor links on the site a `target="_blank"` which is an option that you can select into the WYSIWYG editor of wordpress (no hack).

So if this option IS availible, why doesn't it validate?

And if to validate you have to be in non strict mode why the strict mode is defined?

I know there is a JavaScript hack.. but I don't what to go that way!....

Solution anybody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research... i go with the have... instead of using target="_blank" i use a class="external" and use javascript to change all class to target blank... it validate and work fine...

Answer (score 0):

That fragment seems to validate as HTML 4.01 Transitional and HTML 5. Validation is nothing without a doctype, what's yours?

Comment: a simple show source show me : <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">...it's really limitating, but it's wordpress choice !